# First-order linear differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, first-order-logic

I have this question, and the working out below is as far as I can get:
$$
x \frac{dy}{dx} - y = y^2
\\
p(x) = -\frac{1}{x} 
\\
q(x) = \frac{y^2}{x}
\\
u(x)= e^{\int -\frac{1}{x}dx} \rightarrow \frac{1}{x}
\\
y = \frac{\int \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \left( \frac{y^2}{x} \right)dx }{x^{-1}}
$$

How do I find $$\int \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \left( \frac{y^2}{x^2} \right)dx $$ Wolfram aplha says the indefinite integral is equal to $$-\frac{y^2}{x} + C$$ But I have no clue on how they got that answer, unless you treat $y^2$  as a constant? Can someone please show me how to integrate it, or tell me which method to use? If there was no $y$ terms I would have just used integration by parts, but I got confused. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Samir, for more on separable differential equations, try [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQuBVa5PPy4) for a start.

Comment: Can you please confirm whether or not $$ y = \frac{x}{1-x} $$ ? Thank you in advance @David

Comment: That can't be quite right because when you did the integration you should have introduced an arbitrary constant.  However it is almost right: I got $$y=\frac{Ax}{1-Ax}$$ for any constant $A$.

Comment: Instead of introducing an arbitrary constant during integration, would I be able to put it infront of the $x$ terms after I have found $y$? @David

Comment: Dangerous. . . it would be right in this case but often not.  To be sure you get it right, you need to add a constant *in the same step* where you do the integration(s).  Here, one of your integrals will be $$\int\frac{dx}{x}=\ln x+C$$ which can be written$$\int\frac{dx}{x}=\ln(Ax)$$ where $A=e^C$.

Comment: $$ \int \frac{dy}{y(y+1)} = \int \frac{dx}{Ax}$$ Is this what you mean? If so, then I understand, if not, I don't. @David

Comment: I just realised you edited your answer, makes complete sense, thank you! I appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome!  I can recommend the Youtube channel I mentioned before if you want to learn more about DEs.

Comment: I will definitelly check them out as soon as I finish up on mymathsonline.com.au! Thank you again, btw, I am a student in year 11 and was wondering whether or not you would mind if I email you with a few questions, since I saw your webpage and noticed you taught at UNSW, which is where I was planning to go, thank you nonetheless! @David

Comment: Typo, *definitely

Comment: That would be fine, you can find my address through the UNSW website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you are using the formula for a first order linear DE.  But this DE is not linear (because of the $y^2$) and so you cannot use this method.

**Hint**.  Write the DE as
$$x\frac{dy}{dx}=y+y^2\ .$$
Then you should be able to recognise this as a special type of DE, probably the first type you learnt, and apply the standard solution procedure for this type.  Good luck!

**Another comment**: going from
$$y = \frac{\int \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \left( \frac{y^2}{x} \right)dx }{x^{-1}}
$$
to
$$\int \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \left( \frac{y^2}{x^2} \right)dx\ ,$$
you have taken the factor $x^{-1}$ inside the integral sign (sort of).  But you can't do this because $x^{-1}$ is not a constant.